# Java: Convert String to Date in with Time Zone variable

Tags: java

I have written a func to convert Date String (Thu, 1 Mar 2012 13:57:06 -0600) to Date variable.
I'm relying on SimpleDateFormat for the conversion. The conversion happens, but the resultant Date is "Thu Sep 01 11:00:06 GMT-08:00 2016" which I'm not able to understand. I tried different options for the Format string still invain. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

The options I have tried for the Format String are:
1) E, dd MMM yyyy HH:MM:ss Z
2) EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:MM:ss ZZZZ

```
private Date Convert_To_Date() {

        Date dt = null;

        String str = "Thu, 1 Mar 2012 13:57:06 -0600";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:MM:ss Z");

        try {
            dt = formatter.parse(str);
        }
        catch ( ParseException pe) {
            System.out.println(pe.getMessage());
        }

        //String strDt = dt.toString(); 
        System.out.println(dt);

        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem was just that you were using "M" for minutes instead of "m". This works fine for me:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String text = "Thu, 1 Mar 2012 13:57:06 -0600";
        // Note the explicit locale. Let's not leave it as the system default :)
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", 
                                                    Locale.US);

        Date dt = formatter.parse(text);
        System.out.println(dt);
    }
}
```

(As noted by sgmorrison, you can use `d` instead of `dd` too, and that would be a more accurate description of your format - but `dd` works for parsing in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of small bugs in your date format string:

Your pattern for matching minutes in the hour should be "mm", not "MM" (which matches month of the year). See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for details.

Also, your pattern for matching days in the month should be "d" instead of "dd", as "the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields."

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse( 
    "Thu, 1 Mar 2012 13:57:06 -0600" ,    // Input complies with RFC 1123 & RFC 822.
    DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME  // Hard-coded to English locale.
).toString()
```

> 2012-03-01T13:57:06-06:00

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

## RFC 1123 / RFC 822

Your input string happens to comply with [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) / [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822). The [`java.time.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class defines a constant for that format, [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).

```
String input = "Thu, 1 Mar 2012 13:57:06 -0600" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> 2012-03-01T13:57:06-06:00

Those RFCs are old. The format is outmoded now by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The old format is terrible: assuming English, tolerating a wide-variety of content, and is difficult to parse.

Most every modern protocol and standard uses [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for exchanging date-time values as text. The formats defined by this standard are practical, unambiguous even across cultures, easy to parse by machine, and easy to read by humans for debugging/logging.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings, as seen in examples above.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).