# How to use offset time in Java Simple Date Format

Tags: java

When I am running the below code to convert the time string to Java date, it is failing.

```
String s = "04/17/2017 06:46:53 -600";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date value = format.parse(s);

Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04/17/2017 06:46:53 -600"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

What is the correct format string to be used to convert the date string to java date ?

Comment: Might need to be `-0600` not `-600`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541043/java-convert-string-to-date-in-with-time-zone-variable?rq=1

Comment: you might have to add locale

Comment: @AxelH is correct. Doc: *RFC822TimeZone: Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes*

Comment: from the docs - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html . AxelH is right

Comment: yes, Alex is right, I got the format wrong from external source.

Comment: I've just add a small part in the answer too include every format possible. This might not be readable here (tell me if it isn't) but I doubt the java doc will died anytime ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add -0600 instead -600   [read link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone)

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
class TestFormatDate {


public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception{

String s = "04/17/2017 06:46:53 -0600";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date value = format.parse(s);
System.out.println("value "+value); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [SimpleDateFormat time zone documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone) explain :

> RFC 822 time zone: For formatting, the RFC 822 4-digit time zone format is used:

```
RFC822TimeZone:
         Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes
 TwoDigitHours:
         Digit Digit
```

> ISO 8601 Time zone: The number of pattern letters designates the format for both formatting and parsing as follows:

```
ISO8601TimeZone:
         OneLetterISO8601TimeZone
         TwoLetterISO8601TimeZone
         ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone
    OneLetterISO8601TimeZone:
         Sign TwoDigitHours
         Z
    TwoLetterISO8601TimeZone:
         Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes
         Z
    ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone:
         Sign TwoDigitHours : Minutes
         Z
```

Hours is always seen with two digits so you need to pass `-0600` as a timezone or `-06`

The only way you can have a one digit hours is with `:`

> General time zone: Time zones are interpreted as text if they have names. For time zones representing a GMT offset value, the following syntax is used:

```
GMTOffsetTimeZone:
         GMT Sign Hours : Minutes
 Sign: one of
         + -
 Hours:
         Digit
         Digit Digit
 Minutes:
         Digit Digit
 Digit: one of
         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
String s = "04/17/2017 06:46:53 -0600";
```

Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) to check how to use "Z".