# Converting String of different timezone to date of different timezone

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I have had look to answers mentioned already but they don't tackle the problem I am facing.

I have a String in GMT as:

> 2017-10-03T19:45:00.000+0000

Which I need to parse as any other time zone. The problem is those `+0000`. 
When I try to parse it using `SimpleDateFormat` it does take server timezone into consideration instead of taking user's timeZone.

Here I have created a demo of the issue: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/java/jdk-1.8/92U

Code:

```
String dateString = "2017-10-02T19:45:23.000+0000";
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+0000"); 
parseFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 
try{
    Date newDate = parseFormat.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(newDate);
    parseFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")); 
    String newDateString = parseFormat.format(newDate);
    //Instead of +0000 it should be +05:30 but it is not so. 
    System.out.println(newDateString);
} catch(ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

> Mon Oct 02 19:45:23 GMT 2017
>   2017-10-03T01:15:23.000+0000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use offset time in Java Simple Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518627/how-to-use-offset-time-in-java-simple-date-format)

Comment: `+0000` means UTC.

Comment: And it's better to include the code in the question, so if the link is unavailable, the question doesn't become "incomplete": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339451/7605325

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hugo for the edit.

Comment: @AashirwadGupta You're welcome. But remember that you can always [edit] your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The other Answers suggesting replacing `+0000` with `Z` are correct as a practical workaround, but use troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

```
String input = "2017-10-03T19:45:00.000+0000".replace( "+0000" , "Z" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

For more info, see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39133828/642706).

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem. I did replace the pattern to have a Z in the end.

Answer (score -1):

Please set the timezone of parser to IST before parsing the date.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class MyClass{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String dateString = "2017-10-02T19:45:23.000+0000";
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); 
        //parseFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 
        try{
            parseFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")); 
            Date newDate = parseFormat.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println(newDate);
            String newDateString = parseFormat.format(newDate);
            //Instead of +0000 it should be +05:30 but it is not so. 
            System.out.println(newDateString);
        } catch(ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
Mon Oct 02 19:45:23 GMT 2017
2017-10-03T01:15:23.000+0530
```

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem. I did replace the pattern to have a Z in the end.

Answer (score -2):

Change the `+0000` to `Z`:

```
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem. I did replace the pattern to have a Z in the end.